# .htaccess ?id=__ need to modify htaccess to allow for any id number

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a dynamically created url:
`http://www.mysite.com/?id=1&title=Home` (but really the `id` can be any number up to 999)

So far I have this in my `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)$ /folder/?id=1&title=$1 [L]'
```

This shortens the URL to `www.mysite.com/folder/title`.  However, I do not know how to modify the `RewriteRule` (or add a `RewriteCond`) to allow for the `?id=__` to be any number up to three integers i.e. 1 to 999.  There is information displayed on these pages that goes off of the id number as the primary key from the MySQL and it needs to be intact on each page so that the information pulls correctly.  Please let me know if this is possible or not.

Comment: So what should the short URLs with ID look like?

Comment: I do not want the Id to be displayed in the URL I would simply like the .htaccess to allow for any range of ids possible all the way up to 999.  The dynamic pages pull in data from a db based on the id.

Comment: ...so where does the ID come from, then, if not from the URL?

Comment: As I said above, it's used with and from the mysql db in conjunction with other elements.  The ID is used to pull information from the db and display the information on the page.  I went off of a tutorial to create a cms from http://fwebde.com/web-design/creating-a-php-cms-part-7/ .  The ID is displayed in the URL.  Is there or is there NOT a way to simply tell the .htaccess rewrite to allow a range of Id's and not have the ID display in the URL.  If I need to rewrite how the url is created and displayed please tell me how I am not sure.  Please review tutorial if needed.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I honestly don't think I can answer your question.  You seem to be saying that you want the ID to be included in the URL and _don't_ want the ID to be included in the URL, both at the same time.  Either I don't understand what you're asking, or you're confused about something fundamental yourself.

Comment: All I want is how to write the code for the .htaccess to allow for ?id= to be any integer it's something like ?id=([0-9]+) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question seems incomplete. But I have simple solution.

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)folder/(.*)$ /folder/?title=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

if you open this URL www.mysite.com/folder/title123?id=5 then you will get title123 in `$_GET['title']` and 5 in `$_GET['id']`